# How do I take a value from a function, and use it in another function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the output of 'translated' and use is as an input into 'translated2'but I am getting an error: "'Translated' object is not iterable". I can't work out how to take a value from a function, and put it into another function (aside from print). Very basic question...

See code below:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

#translates text to English
translated = translator.translate('Guten abend')

#translates text from English to another language
translated2 = translator.translate(translated, src='en', dest='mn')

print(translated2.text)
```

Comment: What value is in `translated`? I'm guessing that it should be a string, but maybe it is Null. Is `translator.translate('Guten abend')` returning what you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With translated2 you are trying to translate an object of type `'googletrans.models.Translated'` (remember your translator is an instance of class Translator())

The argument needs to be a string, which you get by calling `translated.text`.

As such, translated2 should look like this:

```
translated2 = translator.translate(translated.text, src='en', dest='mn')
```

**Useful tip:** use `type(obj)` to find out your data type e.g.

```
type(translated) returns <class 'googletrans.models.Translated'>

type(translated.text) returns <class 'str'>
```

Comment: That's great - thank you, and thanks for the additional tip - very handy!